# Is there a command for CMD or C# to find a specific in file, and then copy that file to other folder?

Tags: c#, cmd

i'm try to make batch file, with command that find files contains specific word, and then copy/move that files to some folder, how i do that?

i try this:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.txt /b /a-d ^|find "hello" ') do copy "%%a" C:\final
pause
```

It copies the files whose names are "hey" but not the files that contain "- hey"

Comment: The DIR command is sending the file `name` down the pipeline. FIND is examining the file `name` and not the contents of the file.

Comment: Should the file name contain the specific word or should the file content contain the word?

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt content contain the word. 
i mean, if i have 
1.txt content contain "hey"
2.txt content contain "hello"
3.txt content contain "hey"

then, only files 1 and 3 will be copied

Comment: If you are asking if you could write such a thing in C# (or any other language) then yes you can.

Comment: @CetinBasoz im asking how? and it is possible with CMD?

Comment: You probably want [findstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr#examples) rather than 'find'.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' so, how i wrote it?

Comment: Is this a C# question or a batch/`cmd` question?  Leaving it open to two languages that are not even remotely similar seems to make this too broad.  See [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) where it says "if your question ... has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are _correct_), then it is probably too broad for our format".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you could do it like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var searchFor = "hello";
    var folder = @"c:\temp";
    var files = new DirectoryInfo(folder)
    .GetFiles("*.txt",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(n => Regex.IsMatch(File.ReadAllText(n.FullName),searchFor,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));

    foreach (var f in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f.FullName);
    }
}
```

If you are looking for a ready utility check voidtools' Everything. Total Commander's Alt+F7 is another one, and there are others.

Answer (score 1):

You try to `find` your string within the output of the `dir` command, so you get only file names that contain the string *in the file name*.

`findstr /m "hello" *.txt` gives you the file names of the files that contain the search string (see `findstr /?` for details). Put a `for /f` loop araound to process those files:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /m "hello" *.txt') do copy "%%a" C:\final\
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell you could do the following. When you are confident that the correct files will be copied, remove the `-WhatIf` from `Copy-Item`.

```
$FileDir = 'C:\src\t'
$FileFilter = '*.txt'
$Pattern = 'hello'
$NewDir = $Env:TEMP

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $FileDir -Filter $FileFilter |
    ForEach-Object {
        if (Select-String -Path $_ -Pattern $Pattern -Quiet) {
            Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination $NewDir -WhatIf
        }
    }
```